# Community User has just 1 account?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, area-51, community-user

I noticed that [Community♦ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) was active recently(I lost 4 reps on SO and gained 4 on MSO) so I just checked the profile for **him/her/it**.

First of all, I just noticed that only [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) account was being listed under the [SE accounts section](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts). Then I further noticed that it was because our dear "Community" has earned 2 bronze badges on Area51(namely [Advocate](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/203/advocate?userid=-1) and [Filibuster](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/7/filibuster?userid=-1)).

So, how can it be so that it can earn badges only at Area51 and not on SO/MSO or other sister sites for the same actions?

[image: On SO]

<sub>On Stack Overflow</sub>

[image: On MSO]

<sub>On Meta Stack Overflow</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for Area51 branched off from the SE code years ago. It does not behave the same in many aspects; I guess one of them is its way of handling the badge scripts.

Remember, this is not the user upvoting; rather it is the user owning certain votes on account deletions/etc